# Delaunay_triangulation_2 in CGAL doesn't keep order of input vertices

Tags: cgal, delaunay

I have a set of points  and I am doing a CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2 with them. However, the order of the points in the resulting triangulation is not the same as in the input points. For example, is input point 0 is in (-1,-1), the output point 0 in the triangulation is not in the same position. The point in position (-1,-1) is another one, but not necesarily the 0th.

For me, it is important to keep the order, as I am taking some references (as indices) to the original set of points, so I need the vertex number i in the input set and in the output set to be the same one.

Is there any way to make the output set be ordered the same as the input set? I dont care if I need to reorder the input set, as I can easily do that before taking the references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/classCGAL_1_1Delaunay__triangulation__2.html#a2c02556452fea3d9e3f6cbd332d8c126): "Note that this function is not guaranteed to insert the points following the order of PointInputIterator, as spatial_sort() is used to improve efficiency."

If you insert your points one by one then they will be in the insertion order (provided there is no duplicate).

See also [this example](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/Triangulation_2_2info_insert_with_transform_iterator_2_8cpp-example.html) that can be used to set input id as `info()` of vertices (then a vector can be created to have direct access from id -> vertex).

Comment: Thanks, I have change to insert one by one (they are not too many). This solve me sending the data to a python script, calling paraview.Delaunay2D and returning back. Works fine